# Getting the details of files in a zip folder in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

My question is related to zip files in sharepoint search results.
In the search properties of the zip file i am able to find "HitHighlightedSummary" which seems to be the sentence due to which the zip folder is a part the search results.

I am looking at either getting the file name from the zip folder which is relevant for the search else a relevance based sorted list of files from the zip folder.

[image: Properties Snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online does not index the contents of ZIP files (that I have ever seen). The results will only include the ZIP file name and the associated metadata.